# How can I access to created "View modes" in views and create a block of it?

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I created a *"View modes"* in `Structure> Display-modes> View` and I'm now trying to get access to it in views so i can be able to create a block of it.

By default in Drupal it's possible to create a block of `teasers` and `full posts` but I'm going to create a block of my own "View modes",

I cleared my cash several times but howsoever i try the "View modes" that's i created doesn't show in "Block display settings" dropdown menu and I can't create a block of it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just skip this part of creating a View. Don't create a block or page display yet (that's what I do) and work on a master view. When you go select rendered content as a field, you will have view modes you created as options. Show "Content" as a view mode.

See this for more:

- https://www.amazeelabs.com/en/blog/views-field-rewriting-to-views-modes

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you a lot, for your best and appropriate answer.